# YouTube api - how to get channel views for last 30 days

Tags: php, laravel, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So after reading the documentation of youtube api I have successfully make an oauth connection for youtube account on my server side app but I failed to find a solution on how to get channel views by using this data I obtained. 
So my code looks like this (the PHP part):

```
class YouTube {

    protected $token;

    protected $params = [];

    /**
     * YouTube constructor.
     *
     * @param null $id
     */
    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        if ($id) {
            $this->token = $this->getToken($id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get api authorization
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        // Make redirect
        $this->params = [
            'client_id'    => '########',
            'redirect_uri' => '######',
            'scope'        => 'https://gdata.youtube.com&',
            'response_type'=> 'code&',
            'access_type'  => 'offline'
        ];
        $redirect_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' . http_build_query($this->params);

        return $redirect_url;
    }

    /**
     * Get API token and save account list to db
     *
     * @param $code
     *
     * @return \App\Models\DynamicDashboard\ThirdPartyAccounts
     */
    public function getCallbackUrl($code)
    {
        // Grab the returned code and extract the access token.
        $this->params = [
            'code'          => $code,
            'client_id'     => '####',
            'client_secret' => '#####',
            'redirect_uri'  => '#######',
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code'
        ];

        // Get access token
        $command = 'curl --data "' . http_build_query($this->params) . '" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
        exec($command, $resultToken);
        $resultToken = json_decode($resultToken[0]);

        // Do a request using the access token to get the list of accounts.
        $command = 'curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ' . $resultToken->access_token . '" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2.json';
        exec($command, $result);
        $result = json_decode($result[0]);

        // Save data to db
        $account = new ThirdPartyAccounts();
        $account->account_id = $result->identity->id;
        $account->type = 'youtube';
        $account->name = $result->identity->first_name . ' ' . $result->identity->last_name;
        $account->extra_details = json_encode([
            'access_token'  => $resultToken->access_token,
            'token_type'     => $resultToken->token_type,
            'expires_in'    => $resultToken->expires_in,
            'refresh_token' => $resultToken->refresh_token
        ]);

        $account->save();

        return $account;
    }

    /**
     * Get API token
     *
     * @param $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getToken($id)
    {
        $mainAccount = ThirdPartyAccounts::find($id);
        $youtubeToken = json_decode($mainAccount->extra_details);

        return $youtubeToken;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to make use of this data, I don't know how to write the method required to get the channel views for the last 30 days (with data for every day).
Sorry but I really don't know enough about api connection in order to understand what to do so if you would be so kind as to explain to me what to do any help would be welcomed. Thank you all in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reports.query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/) method to do this. It lets you retrieve many different Analytics reports. Each request uses query parameters to specify a channel ID or content owner, a start date, an end date, and at least one metric. You can also provide additional query parameters, such as dimensions, filters, or sorting instructions.

There's an example in the link provided to retrieve last 30 days but it's written in App Script:

```
var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(
'channel==' + channelId,
oneMonthAgoFormatted,
todayFormatted,
'views,likes,dislikes,shares',
{
dimensions: 'day',
sort: '-day'
});
```

To do this in PHP, I suggest looking at the [Youtube PHP code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/code_samples/php). It is rife with guide and instructions.